# Axis and angle of rotation from 3x3 rotation matrix and properties of rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, coordinate-systems, 3d, rotations

A 3x3 rotation matrix is given. We know the properties of rotation matrix:

- The columns of rotation matrix are unit vectors perpendicular to each other.
- The column vectors indicate where the unit vectors along the principal axes are transformed.
- The rows of rotation matrix are unit vectors perpendicular to each other.
- The row vectors indicate the vectors that are transformed into the unit vectors along the principal axes.
- The inverse of rotation matrix is its transpose.

Suppose, we don't know anything about the Rodrigues formula, so we can't use Trace(R) = 1+2cos$\theta$. Is it possible to find the axis and angle of rotation from the given rotation matrix and the properties of rotation matrix? I need an answer with proper explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is your rotation matrix, then the axis can be found by solving the vector equation $Ax=x$. Take a unit vector $u$ along the axis, another unit vector $v$
perpendicular to $u$ (say by Gram-Schmidt) and $w=u\times v$ (vector product). Then
$Av=(\cos\theta )v+(\sin\theta)w$ for some $\theta$ (that's the angle of rotation).

The right way to find $\theta$ is of course to use $\text{trace}(A)=1+2\cos\theta$.

Comment: This means the rotation matrix has 3 eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs. The eigenvector with eigenvalue 1 is the rotation axis. The two other eigenvalues are $e^{\pm i\theta}$.